# How can US universities check whether graduate students work outside TA/RA?

Tags: united-states, part-time

Some US universities [ban](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/115175/452) first-year graduate students from working outside TA/RA.

How can US universities check whether graduate students work outside TA/RA?

Comment: They likely don’t go out of their way to check, but if you are their waiter at a restaurant there might be raised eyebrows. Actually, the professors don’t care unless it is impacting work.

Comment: ...where “raised eyebrows” means “you lose your TAship”.

Comment: They have them followed ... Obviously not but if their work suffers  and it comes to light then they can act as necessary.

Comment: If they have no way to check, feel free to convert your comments into an answer.

Comment: Why do you ask? Is it a purely hypothetical or do you think that you somehow need to respond to a violation?

Comment: For people on a student visa, off-campus employment is illegal except in narrow circumstances (and always requiring the university’s permission). So the checking is done by the law in that case.

Answer (score 1):

How **can** they or how **do** they?

The chances are pretty slim that a university is able to follow-up on graduate students extracurricular lives.  Perhaps it happens if someone gives them reasons to but it is still very unlikely. The **exception** to this is within the university system -- I would expect that to be easier for them to do (as pointed out by Jon Custer in the comments).

How can they?  Well, anything is possible. Someone could make this their investigative mission.  They could hire someone like a private investigator.  They could play secret agent themselves and follow you.  These all are possible but unlikely.

Comment: When rolling a dice, it's preferable to know how bias it is.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt I agree, that's why I attempted to give the likelihood just before the attempted humor comment.  Apparently I didn't do a good job.  I'll adjust my answer accordingly.  Thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: I'll note that "how **should** they" is another aspect of this.

Comment: I'm still hazy on the context to this question as it affects the answer considerably.